# Basic Question: how should I read this instruction?

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions

I'm very new at using Mathematica and it's not my Job. It's just something I like.

```
data = MapAt[DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] &,
  Import["D:\\Sheet 1.tsv"][[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
 , {All, 1}]
```

I have found out that `DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]` seems to be a function can I define it in a variable and reuse? It would be clearer for me.

Should I write `f[x] := DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]` ?

I'm a c# developer and we would call it "Refactor\Introduce a new variable".
May I do the same also for Import["D:\Sheet 1.tsv"]?
I guess I can but then what is [[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]?

This are the data which of the example, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmv_C2_J7uG8zIhxe5aYZbg79MREI8ePsFJTStSKEeE/edit#gid=0

Comment: you can use `ClearAll[f]; f[x] := DateString[{x, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] ` or `ClearAll[f]; f= DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]&; `

Comment: What  the & stands for?

Comment: Revious, see [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) in the docs.

Comment: @kglr: thanks, do you know also where I can find the documentation to understand this piece of code:  [[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]?

Comment: try [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and [Span (;;)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html). In general, highlight the `[[` or `]]` and hit `F1` to get the related documentation page. Similarly, highlight `;;` and hit `F1`, highlight `&` and hit `F1` etc.

Comment: @kglr; I really appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Revious, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function `f` in several ways

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f[x_] := DateString[{x, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]
```

or

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f = DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]&
```

or

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f = Function[DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]]
```

Import your data:

```
imp = Import["D:\\Sheet 1.tsv"];
```

Take rows from the third row to the last (`3;;`) and columns 1 and 2 (`{1,2}`) from `imp`:

```
data = imp[[3 ;;, {1, 2}]];
```

Map `f` on entries in column 1:

```
data = MapAt[f, data, {All, 1}]
```

**See also:**

- [tutorial/PureFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)
- [tutorial/DefiningFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

Comment: just another question. I got an error by doing: ClearAll[f];
ClearAll[file1];
f[x] := DateString[{x, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}];
file1 = Import["C:\\Users\\Utente\\Documents\\1.csv"];
file1[[2 ;;], {1, 2}]

Comment: it says: Syntax::sntxf: "file1[" cannot be followed by "[2;;],{1,2}]".

Comment: My mistake, I misplaced the ,

Comment: aren't you missing the pattern underscore for the argument to  `f`? I think that should be `f[x_]:=...`

Comment: Thank you @AlbertRetey; corrected the typo.